# Union and Difference with grep

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to use grep to match specific words from a list. 
assume list contains

```
aa
der
bb
abc ref
```

if my understanding is correct, (i tried this with grep -E)

```
cat file | grep '[a-z&&[^m-r]]'
```

should return

```
 aa and bb
```

(matches all the letters from a to z, except m through r). But i'm getting nothing. is something missing here ?

Comment: Please describe the pattern you're trying to match.

Comment: any letter/word between a-z except m through r.

Comment: There is no intersection operator in regex. If it existed, it might be a single (not double) `&`, but operators cannot be used inside character classes anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead.  Saying:

```
grep -P '^[a-z](?!.*[m-z])' filename
```

would return

```
aa
bb
```

for your input.

Comment: Why so complex? My interpretation of the requirement would suggest `^[a-ls-z]*$`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just invert the grep match using the `-v` switch:

```
cat myfile.txt | grep -v '[m-r]'
```

Or without piping:

```
grep -v '[m-r]' myfile.txt
```